# SVN (Apache configuration): Can not disable anonymous access

Tags: svn

I'm trying to setup an SVN Apache based in centos. I need this repo to be private (anonymous access not allowed). But it's driving me crazy...

If I allow read access to everyone, the server correctly request for user and password for write access.

But If I disable read access for everyone, nobody can access.. the server don't even ask for credentials, it just answer with Forbidden response. Even if I try to access using URL authentication (http://user:password@URL:port)

I'm not trying to do anything complex here...

My configuration:

This is /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

```
<Location /svn/>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   SVNListParentPath on

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/svn/svn-policy-file
   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      # SSLRequireSSL

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Authorization Realm"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
      Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

This is /var/www/svn/svn-policy-file

```
[/]
* = 
user1 = rw
user2 = rw

[Repo:/Proyectos/Proy1]
user3 = rw
user4 = r
```

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: Not related, but - your possible next trouble: there is your DocumentRoot? Any chances for `/var/www/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `AuthzSVNAccessFile` play game (you have module added), you can have

```
<Location /svn/>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   SVNListParentPath on

      AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/svn/svn-policy-file  
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Authorization Realm"
      AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
      Satisfy any
      Require valid-user
</Location>
```

with AuthzSVNAccessFile starting from

```
[/]
* =
```

(LimitExcept container removed, Satisfy added): [Examples 2 and 3](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_authz_svn/INSTALL) from "Configuration" section (I don't have 3 in action to confirm functionality, always use 2)